# Espaçamento em um GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Eu tenho em meu projeto android um gridview que eu defino da seguinte forma:
Criei um XML Adapter, logo, o gridview corta algumas letras (icons), como representa a imagem a baixo. Como comecei agora a desenvolver, não sei sobre as propriedades do gridview. Obs: Segui esse tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.a, R.drawable.n,
        R.drawable.b, R.drawable.o,
        R.drawable.c, R.drawable.p,
        R.drawable.d, R.drawable.q,
        R.drawable.e, R.drawable.r,
        R.drawable.f, R.drawable.s,
        R.drawable.g, R.drawable.t,
        R.drawable.h, R.drawable.u,
        R.drawable.i, R.drawable.v,
        R.drawable.j, R.drawable.w,
        R.drawable.k, R.drawable.x,
        R.drawable.l, R.drawable.y,
        R.drawable.m, R.drawable.z
};
```

}

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Você teve que criar um adapter, certo? Edita a pergunta ai e coloca o .xml do adapter, o problema deve estar lá.

Comment: Max, fiz isso aqui agora. O que acha?

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque voce definiu o Colum Width = 65dp... tente defina o dp maior que 65 ja que o seu icon (Imagem das letras) esta sendo cortado.

Comment: Essa resolução não funcionou. O "matchparent" não é aceito, no ColumWidth

Comment: Tentou aumentar o dp do columWidht? Caso ja tenha feito, verifique o layout do adapter e aumente o textView dele. Caso tenha duvidas me avise :D

Comment: Tentei sim. Arrumei pelo xmd do adapter mesmo. Agora to com duas dúvidas, que é conseguir aumentar meus icons. E outra, se é possivel colocar função para cada icon desse? Pq no caso, eu não criei "imageButton". Tem algum tutorial pra isso?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema. 
Na linha " imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);" no XML adapter.
Alterei de "CENTER_CROP" para "FIT_END" e resolveu meu problema.

Porém, gostaria de aumentar(expandir) meus icons. Existe um espaço entre eles.

][image: Atualizado]